# Minimalistic scrollspy changing active class just to a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, scrollspy

Anyone could solve this? It's a code on minimalistic scrollspy. It adds active class when content is offset.top. I know this code works but could I know if there's a way to change active class to the "a" tag instead of its parent? I removed .parent() but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want the whole li to be active. Thanks in advance.

Codepen: https://jsfiddle.net/mekwall/up4nu/

HTML

```
<nav class="clearfix">
      <ul class="clearfix" id="top-menu">
        <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#aboutus">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#testimonial">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contactus">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
// Cache selectors
var lastId,
    topMenu = $("#top-menu"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    // All list items
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a"),
    // Anchors corresponding to menu items
    scrollItems = menuItems.map(function(){
      var item = $($(this).attr("href"));
      if (item.length) { return item; }
    });

// Bind click handler to menu items
// so we can get a fancy scroll animation
menuItems.click(function(e){
  var href = $(this).attr("href"),
      offsetTop = href === "#" ? 0 : $(href).offset().top-topMenuHeight+1;
  $('html, body').stop().animate({ 
      scrollTop: offsetTop
  }, 300);
  e.preventDefault();
});

// Bind to scroll
$(window).scroll(function(){
   // Get container scroll position
   var fromTop = $(this).scrollTop()+topMenuHeight;

   // Get id of current scroll item
   var cur = scrollItems.map(function(){
     if ($(this).offset().top < fromTop)
       return this;
   });
   // Get the id of the current element
   cur = cur[cur.length-1];
   var id = cur && cur.length ? cur[0].id : "";

   if (lastId !== id) {
       lastId = id;
       // Set/remove active class -- This is the part.
       menuItems
         .parent().removeClass("active")
         .end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
   }                   
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here an updated working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/3L8v12f6/)

First I added a CSS for a.active, because it fits the [li] space so was impossible to discern what was active.

Then you must set starting as active the  tag instead the [li]

Now you can change your last 2 javascript rows to

```
menuItems
         .parent().find('a').removeClass("active")
         .find('a').end().filter("[href='#"+id+"']").addClass("active");
```

using find('a') to get the right tag.